# Form of wave function of a free particle in the void

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Thanks to the answer of Stoby, I clarify my question

It seems a silly question  but I wonder which form would take the wave function of a free particle alone in the void ?

I understood that in this case the main parameter would be its mass but would it results to a very large wave function ?

And what about particle that has no mass like the photon ?

EDIT :
Thanks to the comment of Stoby, I could make some complementary research about the topic.

My understanding is that the wave function is theoretically plane (so it is not really a wave anymore) and in this situation, the wave function equation is not able to describe the reality of the particle. My understanding of this impossibility is not that the equation is wrong but that this theoretical situation is not possible because there is not a place that is both totally empty and infinite (unless it is the last particle in the universe I suppose....)

Does this understanding is correct ?

Comment: It depends on the potential $V(\mathbf{r})$ the particle is subjected to.

Comment: Its tough to say exactly what "the void" means. But if you mean a particle alone in empty space, see this article (or just google free solution to Schrodinger equation) https://www.dummies.com/education/science/quantum-physics/how-to-solve-the-schrdinger-equation-for-free-particles/ (Also keep in mind, a free, time-independent Schrodinger equation is just a second order ODE with complex characteristic roots so if you know diff eq, that helps)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the situation I wanted to describe. When the particle has V(x) is null. Your link (and other google result) is very clear to the point that the result is a plane wave which is, as I understood, physically impossible. But I don't understand what follow this point (seems that the redaction is unfinished or missing conclusion). Does it means that the equation can't apply here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the plane wave cannot physically describe the particle in reality, as it can’t be normalised. The correct normalisable wave function for a free particle would be a gaussian. It can be constructed by adding together many plane waves. Basically this corresponds to how a particle in reality would not have a definite momentum, unlike the plane wave solution. The plane wave solution can be seen as an extreme consequence of the heisenberg uncertainty principle. A plane wave represents a particle with definite momentum, and as a result it’s position is totally undefined. In order to describe the free particle more realistically, you need to take into account the fuzzy quantum properties of the particle.

As for photons, photons are inherently relativistic meaning you would have to use Quantum Electrodynamics, a Quantum Field Theory to describe photons. I believe you could find an analogous sort of wave function for a single photon, but it would be in my opinion not much of a useful task.